# Is it possible to extract data from runtime in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I am trying to create an application to which user will send some very sensitive data over the network. Naturally we are going to use HTTPS, so man-in-the-middle attack should not be a concern, but I am considering whether it would be possible for a malicious 3rd party to somehow extract the in-memory data from Node.js process if he would gain access to the machine?

Maybe there are some other considerations when dealing with very sensitive data? We are not going to store the data, rather just process it and return the result.

Comment: `in-memory data from Node.js process`,   Yes, that's for any process not just node.   Security here is then part of the OS.

Comment: if a malicious 3rd party has root access to your server then the game is already over

Answer (score 0):

First off: HTTPS does not mean MITM attacks are impossible and there are still plenty of tricks hackers use (such as xss) to intercept sensitive info.

You should make sure to encrypt all your data heavily.

Second off: Any memory is accessible depending on the state of your machine.

As long as you make process poking a root only permission, you should be fine, but it depends on what's running at any given time and the general security of your os.

I hope this was helpful, cheers!